# floats in twig, format or number_format extension?

Tags: numbers, twig

I have float numbers as:

```
1.01

1.10

1.00
```

I need show these numbers like that:

```
1.01 => 1.01

1.10 => 1.1

1.00 => 1
```

Basically, I need to show the float values. How can i do it ?

Answer (score 4):

I think this code could interrest you :

```
{% set firstValue = 1.100 %}       // return 1.1
firsvalue = {{firstValue }}

{% set secondValue = 1.1001 %}    // return 1.1001
secondValue = {{secondValue }}

{% set thirdValue = 1.000 %}      // return 1
thirdValue = {{thirdValue }}


{% set myValue = 1.50000 %}      // return 1.5
{% set value = myValue %}
value = {{ value }}

{% set myStringValue = '1.50000' %}      // return 1.5 
{% set myvalue = 0 + myStringValue %}
value = {{ myvalue }}
```

I couldn't use `number_format` pipe http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html because it must play with decimal.

If your value is from a string, you can `{% set myvalue = 0 + myStringValue %}`

Comment: "0 + myStringValue" nice hack!